Correct Preposition to Use Before "Compound"
Do I say "Dad was quick to notice that some tents had been erected on Ogenche's compound" or "Dad was quick to notice that some tents had been erected in Ogenche's compound"?

Both are valid.  Generally we use in if the compound is large and on if it is small.
Despite some false positives, in his compound still has lots of valid hits and is more common than on his compound.
in his compound v on his compound
I have used his rather than the as the pair in the compound and on the compound give lots of false positives and are hence hard to evaluate.
